# Tag de bloco inválido

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Sou novo em *Django* e estou com um problema com as tags de *Template*

**Meu código:**

```
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
   <div>
    {{ questao.afirmativa }}
  </div>
    {% alternativas = questao.get_alternativas %}
    <table>
      <tr>
        {% for alternativa in alternativas %}
          <td>{{alternativa}}</td>
        {% end for %}
      </tr>
    </table>
{% endblock content %}
```

O objeto `questao` já vem no `context` da `view`. O método `get_alternativas` gera uma lista de alternativas que quero percorrer com o `for` e mostrar na página.

O que estou fazendo de errado?

Está dando erro nessa linha:

```
{% alternativas = questao.get_alternativas %}
```

Mensagem de erro:

> "*- Tag de bloco inválido na linha 7: 'alternativas', esperado 'endblock'. Você esqueceu de registrar ou carregar esta tag?*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As *tags* `{% ... %}` são exclusivas para os comandos do sistema de templates do **Django** (seja o que vem embutido nele, seja usando o **Jinja2**).

Para criar uma nova variável dentro do modelo, use a *tag* `{% with ... %}`:

```
{% with alternativas as questao.get_alternativas %}
<table>
  <tr>
    {% for alternativa in alternativas %}
      <td>{{alternativa}}</td>
    {% endfor %}
  </tr>
</table>
{% endwith %}
```

Aliás o `{% endfor %}` está grafado errado no teu código.